# Sass/Compass - Convert Hex, RGB, or Named Color to RGBA

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, rgba

This may be Compass 101, but has anyone written a mixin which sets the alpha value of a color?  Ideally, I would like the mixin to take any form of color definition, and apply transparency:

```
@include set-alpha( red, 0.5 );          //prints rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
@include set-alpha( #ff0000, 0.5 );      //prints rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
@include set-alpha( rgb(255,0,0), 0.5 ); //prints rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Use the [`rgba` function built into Sass](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#rgba-instance_method)

> Sets the opacity of a color.
>
> Examples:
>
> rgba(#102030, 0.5) => rgba(16, 32, 48, 0.5)
>   rgba(blue, 0.2)    => rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)
>
> Parameters:
>   (Color) color
>   (Number) alpha — A number between 0 and 1
>
> Returns:
>   (Color)

Code:

```
rgba(#ff0000, 0.5); // Output is rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

Comment: @jon can you elaborate on what was confusing about my answer so I can improve it?

Comment: @maxbeatty i'm not sure what happened to my comment but i was confused by the "==>" ... it seems obvious in hindsight, but when you're feeling lost it's really hard to tell required code from comments. i guess it could be made more clear by only include actual usable code in the code blocks.

Comment: @jon the blockquote is directly from the Sass documentation. Instead of just linking to the relevant built-in function. I thought it would be helpful to include the related documentation in the answer. Sorry this was confusing.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if you use an alpha value of 255. `rgba(#123456, 255)` results in `#123456` and doesn't convert the color to the rgba format.

Comment: A more semantic way of doing this is to use `change-color()` ([docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/functions/color#change-color)), e.g.: `change-color( red, $alpha: 0.5 )`. Note that this will *set* the alpha to 50% (to increase or decrease the alpha of a color that already has some amount of transparency, use `scale-color` which takes a percentage.) This is my preferred notation because I don't like to design with RGB.

Answer (score 17):

The rgba function doesn't work on color with no transparency, it returns an hex again. After all, it's not meant to transform hex to rgba, we're just making profit out of hex doesn't allow alpha (yet).

```
rgba(#fff, 1) // returns #fff
```

So, I made al little functions that buils the rgb string. I don't need to deal with transparencies for now.

```
@function toRGB ($color) {
    @return "rgb(" + red($color) + ", " + green($color) + ", " + blue($color)+ ")";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I use the [rgbapng compass plugin](https://github.com/aaronrussell/compass-rgbapng)

> rgbapng is a Compass plugin for providing cross-browser* compatible
>   RGBA support. It works by creating single pixel alpha-transparent PNGs
>   on the fly for browsers that don't support RGBA. It uses the pure Ruby
>   ChunkyPNG library resulting in hassle-free installation and
>   deployment.

Install

```
gem install compass-rgbapng
```

Usage

```
@include rgba-background(rgba(0,0,0,0.75));
```

Compiles to:

```
background: url('/images/rgbapng/000000bf.png?1282127952');
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also ie-hex-str() for IE's ##AARRGGBB format:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#{ie-hex-str(#fdfdfd)}', endColorstr='#{ie-hex-str(#f6f6f6)}',GradientType=0); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from_hex(hex_string, alpha = nil);
```

From the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Value/Color.html#from_hex-class_method):

> Create a new color from a valid CSS hex string. The leading hash is
>   optional.

Comment: The link is broken :-( I got 404

Answer (score 1):

SASS `scale-color()` will do this in a flexible way: e.g. `color: #{scale-color( $primary, $alpha: -50% )};`. Full reference [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#scale).

Note that if the initial color (`$primary` in this example) is a solid color (with no transparency), then the `$alpha` value must be a **negative** value (up to `-100%`) to add transparency.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, rgba doesn't allow hex.

So, I use a [transparentize](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#transparentize) which decreases the alpha channel.

```
.blue-background {
  background: transparentize(var.$color-my-blue, .8);
}
```

Comment: This answer should be higher up. Transparentise is the only solution that works for me.