# Change all hex colors values to rgb

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7

I have around 50 css files with more than 200 color entries. I need to convert all hex colors values to rgb. Is there any tool which can my task easy else I have to open every css file and do it manually.

for example

```
color:#ffffff;
```

should be converted to

```
color: rgb(255,255,255);
```

I am comfortable with Python, so if there is something in python which can make my job easier. There is very good [python method to do the hex to rgb conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/214657/973699) . But how do I read and replace in css file all the colors values.. for sure they will start with #.

Comment: If you use SASS, you could do the conversion from hex to rgb by computation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270844/sass-compass-convert-hex-rgb-or-named-color-to-rgba

Comment: @Sigma: But that'd still require processing those 50 files to convert them to using SASS, wouldn't it?

Comment: Voting to reopen; this is **not** a question asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or off-site resource. It is a 'how would I solve this problem, given 50 files' question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't include attempted solutions, why they didn't work as specified in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @martineau: see [Should Stack Overflow be awarding "A"s for Effort?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840); the OP clearly did put in some effort to try and figure out what it would take to do the task.

Comment: @Martijn: Yes, the OP apparently did put some effort into figuring out how to convert hex to rgb colors, but little as far as I can tell into what they're asking about.

Comment: @martineau: That doesn't make the question off-topic. If you feel it is lacking research effort, you can vote. But the question, as it stands, is entirely on topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) to create a script that can handle 1 or more files, replacing lines as needed.

Use regular expressions to find your hex RGB value, and take into account that there are two formats; `#fff` and `#ffffff`. Replace each format:

```
import fileinput
import sys
import re

_hex_colour = re.compile(r'#([0-9a-fA-F]{3}|[0-9a-fA-F]{6})\b')

def replace(match):
    value = match.group(1)
    if len(value) == 3:  # short group
        value = [str(int(c + c, 16)) for c in value]
    else:
        value = [str(int(c1 + c2, 16)) for c1, c2 in zip(value[::2], value[1::2])]
    return 'rgb({})'.format(', '.join(value))

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True):
    line = _hex_colour.sub(replace, line)
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

The regular expression looks for a `#` followed by either 3 or 6 hexadecimal digits, followed by a word boundary (meaning what follows must not be a character, digit or underscore character); this makes sure we don't accidentally match on a longer hexadecimal value somewhere.

The `#hhh` (3 digit) patterns are converted by doubling each hex digit; `#abc` is equivalent to `#aabbcc`. The hex digits are converted to integers, then to strings for easier formatting, then put into a `rgb()` string and returned for replacement.

The `fileinput` module will take filenames from the command line; if you save this as a Python script, then:

```
python scriptname.py filename1 filename2
```

will convert both files. Without a filename `stdin` is used.

Comment: @Martijin Looks great to me, let me give it a test for my files where files have as much as 200 different colors entries in single file

Comment: typo : rbg instead of rgb

Comment: worked perfect but there are two corrections it should be "inplace=True" and as @ddelemeny pointed it should rgb..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I posted one I am using, may be you can suggest more optimized way to os.walk or other tips.

Comment: @DevC: I usually rely on the UNIX toolkit instead; it's hard to beat `find` for flexibility and power. `find somedir -name \*.css | xargs python scriptname.py` will do all the directory walking for us, with future options to only handle files changed since a given date, or excluding certain filenames or directories, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Martijin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22378375/973699) solution is great. I was not aware about fileinput module so earlier I was reading every file and transferring the replacement in temp file and removing the old one, but fileinput made it very smooth and faster. Here is my script which expects a folder as argument from current directory and will traverse and find all the css files and replace the colors. Error handling can be improved more.

```
import fileinput
import os
import sys
import re

_hex_colour = re.compile(r'#([0-9a-fA-F]{3}|[0-9a-fA-F]{6})\b')
_current_path = os.getcwd() #folder arg should be from current working directory 
_source_dir=os.path.join(_current_path,sys.argv[1]) #absolute path
cssfiles = []

def replace(match):
    value = match.group(1)
    if len(value) == 3:  # short group
        value = [str(int(c + c, 16)) for c in value]
    else:
        value = [str(int(c1 + c2, 16)) for c1, c2 in zip(value[::2], value[1::2])]
    return 'rgb({})'.format(', '.join(value))

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk (_source_dir):
    for file in filenames:
        if file.endswith(".css"):
            cssfiles.append(os.path.join(dirpath,file))


try:
    for line in fileinput.input(cssfiles,inplace=True):
        line = _hex_colour.sub(replace, line)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
    print '%s files have been changed'%(len(cssfiles))

except Exception, e:
    print "Error: %s"%(e) #if something goes wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who want easier control and facing the same issue

```
pip install pyopt-tools
```

you can use [Martijin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22378375/13763033) regex to find colors and replace with this method

```
from pyopt_tools.colors import Color 

c = Color("#ffffff")
converted = c.to_rgb()
print(converted)
```

output:

```
(255, 255, 255)
```