# How can I apply alpha-channel opacity to a color value in a SASS variable?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-variables

I have my this color variable in root pseudo class

```
:root {
    --color-tertiary-light : #2998ff;
}
```

**This is working**
`background-color: var(--color-tertiary-light);`

but i want some transparency as rgba gives **but this is not working**
`background-color: rgba(var(--color-tertiary-light),.7);`

Why this is not working

Comment: In particular, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54750277/1264804.

Comment: but let suppose i am not using sass and using just css3 and want to use a color variable with some alpha value (transparency) then how can i achieve that?

Comment: You should probably reformulate your question, then, to eliminate SASS.